# Trouble with dynamic input program in C

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am having debugging my program and I cannot seem to find any answers.  My program takes in a file, copies the words to a dynamic array and keeps a word count for multiples.

Problem 1) For what I have compiled I have tried to different input examples.  One reads "foo bar bat bam" and the other "foo foo bar bam".  The first output is all four words in that order, the second prints

```
    foo
    bar     
    bam
    foo bar bam
```

I cannot figure out why this is.

Problem 2)  I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to initialize a newly entered word to count 1. The line

```
arrayOfWords[unique_words].count = 1;
```

is giving me a segmentation fault.  And using  -> does not compile.

Problem 3)  I cannot seem to dynamically grow the array.  I commented them out for now, but you can see my two strategies at attempting to enlarge the array.

I SERIOUSLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP!

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INITIAL_SIZE 10

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef struct { char * word; int count; } wordType;

int main( void )
{
    wordType *arrayOfWords = (wordType*)malloc(1 * sizeof (wordType) ); 
    wordType *tempArray;
    FILE * inputFile;
    char temp[50];
    uint i;
    uint j;
    uint unique_words;
    uint exists;
    uint wordAdded;
    inputFile = fopen( "input.txt", "r");



    if( inputFile == NULL )
    {
            printf("Error: File could not be opened\n" );
            /*report failure*/
            return 1;
    }
    i = 0;
    unique_words = 0;
    wordAdded = 0;
    while( fscanf( inputFile, "%s", temp) != EOF )
    {


        /*if a word was added, then increase the size by one
        if( wordAdded == 1 )
    {
        tempArray = malloc((unique_words + 1) * sizeof(wordType) );
        memcpy( arrayOfWords, tempArray, unique_words + 1 );
        free( tempArray );
        wordAdded = 0;
    } */

    /*
    if( wordAdded == 1 )
    {
        arrayOfWords = realloc(arrayOfWords, unique_words + 1 );
        wordAdded = 0;
    }*/

    exists = 0;
    for( j = 0; j < unique_words; j++ )
    {
        if( strcmp( arrayOfWords[j].word, temp ) == 0 )
        {
            arrayOfWords[j].count++;
            exists = 1;
        }
    }
    if( exists == 0 )
    {
        arrayOfWords[unique_words].word = malloc(sizeof(char)
                                * (strlen(temp)+1));
        strcpy( arrayOfWords[unique_words].word, temp );
        /*arrayOfWords[unique_words].count = 1; */
        unique_words++;
        wordAdded = 1;
    }
    i++;
}
    printf("unique_words = %d\n", unique_words);
    for( i = 0; i < unique_words; i++ )
    printf("%s\n", arrayOfWords[i].word);


    fclose( inputFile );
   /* for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        free( arrayOfWords[0].word );*/
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main( void ){
    wordType *arrayOfWords = NULL;
    FILE * inputFile = stdin; //stdin for simplification
    char temp[50];
    uint i,j;
    uint unique_words;
    uint exists;

    unique_words = 0;
    while( fscanf( inputFile, "%s", temp) != EOF ){
        exists = 0;
        for( j = 0; j < unique_words; j++ ){
            if( strcmp( arrayOfWords[j].word, temp ) == 0 ){
                arrayOfWords[j].count++;
                exists = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( exists == 0){//new word
            arrayOfWords = realloc(arrayOfWords, (unique_words+1)*sizeof(wordType));
            arrayOfWords[unique_words].count = 1;
            arrayOfWords[unique_words].word = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp)+1));
            strcpy(arrayOfWords[unique_words].word, temp );
            ++unique_words;
        }
    }
    printf("unique_words = %d\n", unique_words);
    for( i = 0; i < unique_words; i++ )
        printf("%s\n", arrayOfWords[i].word);

    /* deallcate
    for( i = 0; i < unique_words; ++i)
        free( arrayOfWords[i].word );
    free(arraOfWords);
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this clarifies a lot.  Allocating as needed rather than initializing makes way more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You commented out the reallocation because it didn't work, and now it crashes because you *don't* reallocate.

Just like `malloc`, the `realloc` function needs the size in bytes. You should therefore use e.g.

```
arrayOfWords = realloc(arrayOfWords, sizeof(wordType) * (unique_words + 1));
```

When you get this reallocation working, your program should no longer crash.

---

And in case you're wondering, the crash is because you increase `unique_words` but do not reallocate the buffer. This leads you to access memory outside of the memory you allocated, which is *undefined behavior* and can lead to crashes (or other weird behavior).